# How to generate random number in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell, random

How to generate a random number within a range in Bash?

Comment: How random does it need to be?

Answer (score 578):

Use [`$RANDOM`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/randomvar.html). It's often useful in combination with simple shell arithmetic. For instance, to generate a random number between 1 and 10 (inclusive):

```
$ echo $((1 + $RANDOM % 10))
3
```

The actual generator is in `variables.c`, the function `brand()`. [Older versions](https://www.codeblog.org/viewsrc/bash-3.1/variables.c) were a simple linear generator. Version 4.0 of `bash` uses a [generator with a citation](http://www.bashcookbook.com/bashinfo/source/bash-4.0/variables.c) to [a 1988 paper](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/63039.63042), which presumably means it's a decent source of pseudorandom numbers. I wouldn't use it for a simulation (and certainly not for crypto), but it's probably adequate for basic scripting tasks.

If you're doing something that requires serious random numbers you can  use `/dev/random` or `/dev/urandom` if they're available:

```
$ dd if=/dev/urandom count=4 bs=1 | od -t d
```

Comment: Be careful here.  While this is fine in a pinch, doing arithmetic on random numbers can dramatically affect the randomness of your result.  in the case of `$RANDOM % 10`, 8 and 9 are measurably (though marginally) less probable than 0-7, even if `$RANDOM` is a robust source of random data.

Comment: @dimo414 I'm curious to "marginally", do you have a source where I can find out more about this?

Comment: By moduloing your random input, you are "[pigeon-holing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)" the results.  Since `$RANDOM`'s range is `0-32767` the numbers `0`-`7` map to `3277` different possible inputs, but `8` and `9` can only be produced `3276` different ways (because `32768` and `32769` aren't possible).  This is a minor issue for quick hacks, but means the result is not uniformly random. Random libraries, like Java's `Random`, offer functions to properly return a uniform random number in the given range, rather than simply mod-ing a non-divisible number.

Comment: @dimo414: depending on PRNG, applying `% n` may be even worse. Look at the last picture in [Test PRNG using gray bitmap](https://www.wakari.io/sharing/bundle/jfs/Test%20PRNG%20using%20gray%20bitmap). It shows the obvious skew

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian very true - the problem with modulo is it can break the uniformity of *any* RNG, not just bad PRNGs, but thanks for calling this out.

Comment: Just for context, the basic pigeonholing for % 10 means 8 and 9 are about .03% less likely to occur than 0–7. If your shell script requires more accurate uniform random numbers than that, then by all means use a more complex and proper mechanism.

Comment: On my mac, I had to use `echo $((1 + $RANDOM % 10))` with the `$RANDOM`, not just `RANDOM`.

Comment: $RANDOM has some weird properties in zsh:  Try: `echo $RANDOM; echo $RANDOM`.  Now try `(echo $RANDOM); (echo $RANDOM)`.  The former gives two different numbers, the latter does not.  Using `shuf` avoids this problem.  I think that shuf is the better solution.

Comment: @Eyal According to the docs, the same sequence is repeated by each shell, by design.  You can manually seed the generator and also have subshells share a sequence.
http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-RANDOM

Comment: You need entropy. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/65207245/1208218

Comment: In `(())`, you can skip the prefix `$` of variable, like this `$((1 + RANDOM % 10))`.

Comment: this always retrun 0 for me when I run my script with `sh` and not `bash`. Why is that?

Comment: @CharlieParker, I believe the [arithmetic expansion (`$((  ))`)](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Arithmetic-Expansion) is a bash-only thing that is not supported by `sh`. I don't write scripts in `sh`. I find it much more difficult. `bash` seems to me to be much more powerful.

Comment: I like to see source info. I found it: from `man bash`: `RANDOM    Each time this parameter is referenced, a random integer between 0 and 32767 is generated. The sequence of random numbers may be initialized by assigning a value to RANDOM. If  RANDOM is unset, it loses its special properties, even if it is subsequently reset.`

Answer (score 128):

Please see [`$RANDOM`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/randomvar.html):

> `$RANDOM` is an internal Bash function
>   (not a constant) that returns a
>   pseudorandom integer in the range
>   0 - 32767. It should not be used to
>   generate an encryption key.

Comment: Does `32767` has any special meaning?

Comment: @JinKwon `32767` is `2^16 / 2 - 1` which is the upper limit for a signed 16 bit integer.

Comment: @JinKwon could you clarify why don't you say it is `2^15 - 1`?  It's equivalent, so I'm just curious if there is some context I'm missing?

Comment: @BrettHolman I think he was trying to point out the "signed" part of the signed 16 bit integer. 2^16 values, split in half for postive & negative ints.

Comment: this always retrun 0 for me when I run my script with `sh` and not `bash`. Why is that?

Comment: Shouldn't the range be -32768 to 32767 then?

Comment: @Sidney thats the range of a 16 bit signed integer, but `bash` apparently isnt using the full range.

Comment: If it's a function, why is it referenced with a "$" sign like a variable?

Answer (score 120):

You can also use [`shuf`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/shuf.1.html) (available in coreutils).

```
shuf -i 1-100000 -n 1
```

Comment: How do you pass in vars as range end? I got this: `shuf -i 1-10 -n 1: syntax error in expression (error token is "1-10 -n 1")`

Comment: Add a `$var` instead of the range end, like this: `var=100 && shuf -i 1-${var} -n 1`

Comment: I prefer this option as it's easy to generate N random numbers with `-n`. E.g. *Generate 5 random numbers between 1 and 100*: `shuf -i 1-100 -n 5`

Comment: As far as I understand the numbers are not random. If you specify `shuf -i 1-10 -n 10` you will get all numbers from 1 to 10 exactl one. If you specify `-n 15` you will still get only those 10 numbers exactly once. That is really only shuffling, not generating random numbers.

Comment: To get random numbers with replacement: -r

Comment: @knipwim, What the maximum range ?

Comment: By default, `shuf` doesn't use a  cryptographically secure pseudo-random number generator, but it's possible to use `shuf` with `/dev/urandom` (`--random-source` option). Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/705633/133353 (*By default these commands use an internal pseudo-random generator initialized*...)

Answer (score 54):

Try this from your shell:

```
$ od -A n -t d -N 1 /dev/urandom
```

Here, `-t d` specifies that the output format should be signed decimal; `-N 1` says to read one byte from `/dev/urandom`.

Comment: The question asks for numbers in a range.

Comment: you can remove spaces: `od -A n -t d -N 1 /dev/urandom |tr -d ' '`

Comment: While a great answer for a source of random numbers, one should stress the point that signed decimals from 1 (or more) bytes have the caveat that, like `$RANDOM`, do not end at multiple of 10, and that may skew things if one uses the modulo. So with 1 byte one has up to 255 and thus using, say, %10, would give some digits a bit higher probabilities than others. Same with 2 bytes, 3 and so on.

Answer (score 34):

I like this trick:

```
echo ${RANDOM:0:1} # random number between 1 and 9
echo ${RANDOM:0:2} # random number between 1 and 99
```

...

Comment: $RANDOM is in the range of 0 - 32767.  You will end up with more numbers that start with 1, 2 or 3, than you will 4-9.  If you're okay with an imbalanced distribution, this will work fine.

Comment: @jbo5112 you are totally right, what about display last digit ? echo ${RANDOM:0-1} for one digit, ${RANDOM:0-2} for two digit ... ?

Comment: If you use the last digit(s), it will be rather good, but it it will include 0's and 00's.  On a single digit, 0-7 will occur 0.03% more often than 8-9.  On 2 digits, 0-67 will occur 0.3% more often than 68-99.  If you need a random number distribution that good, hopefully you're not using bash.  With the original: `${RANDOM:0:1}` has a 67.8% chance of giving you a 1 or a 2, `${RANDOM:0:2}` only has a 0.03% chance of giving you a single digit number (should be 1%), and both have a 0.003% chance of giving you a 0.  There are still use cases where this is fine (e.g. non-consistent input).

Comment: This should be good: `echo $((10#${RANDOM: -1}${RANDOM: -1}))` It uses everytime the last digit and leading zeros are removed. For more digits only an additional  `${RANDOM: -1}` needs to be added.

Answer (score 31):

you can also get random number from awk

```
awk 'BEGIN {
   # seed
   srand()
   for (i=1;i<=1000;i++){
     print int(1 + rand() * 100)
   }
}'
```

Comment: +1 you know, at first I though why would you ever want to do it like this, but actually I quite like it.

Comment: Thanks for giving a solution that include seeding. I couldn't find it anywhere!

Comment: +1 for seeding. It might be worth mentioning that `srand()` 's seed is the current CPU time. If you need to specify a specific seed, so RNG can be duplicated, use `srand(x)` where `x` is the seed. Also, quoted from GNU awk's numeric function manual, "different awk implementations use different random-number generators internally." The upshot is that if you are interested in generating statistical distribution, you should expect slight variations going from one runtime to the next on different platform (all running `awk` or `gawk`).

Comment: **BEWARE** `srand()` seeds using the current CPU time in **seconds**, so if you run this script several times in one second, the script will print the same values each time.

If you want to be safe then just replace `srand()` with `srand('$(date +%s%N)')` in the answer above to use the current time in nanoseconds (this does not work on macos at time of writing but should work on Linux)

Answer (score 25):

There is $RANDOM.
I don't know exactly how it works. But it works.
For testing, you can do :

```
echo $RANDOM
```

Comment: How can we get random numbers in a range 1-10

Comment: @ghost21blade `$(( ($RANDOM % 10) + 1 ))`

Answer (score 23):

[bash 5.1](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/NEWS) introduces a new variable, [`SRANDOM`](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#index-SRANDOM), which gets its random data from the system's entropy engine and so is not linear and cannot be reseeded to get an identical random sequence. This variable can be used as a substitute for `RANDOM` for generating *more random* numbers.

```
$ echo $((1 + SRANDOM % 10))
4
```

Answer (score 16):

Random number between 0 and 9 inclusive.

```
echo $((RANDOM%10))
```

Comment: My bad, didn't read the man page properly. `$RANDOM` only goes from 0 to 32767. It should have said "Random number mostly between 1 and 3, with a few wingers" ;)

Comment: What? It'll still be between 0 and 9, though 8 and 9 will have slightly less probability of occurring than 0 through 7, as mentioned in another answer.

Answer (score 9):

I wrote several articles on this.

- https://linuxconfig.org/generating-random-numbers-in-bash-with-examples
- https://linuxconfig.org/random-entropy-in-bash
- https://www.cloudsavvyit.com/7572/how-to-generate-better-random-numbers-at-the-bash-command-line/

```
$ RANDOM=$(date +%s%N | cut -b10-19 | sed 's|^[0]\+||')
$ echo $(( $RANDOM % 113 + 13 ))
```

The above will give a number between 13 and 125 (113-1+13), with reasonable random entropy.

Comment: I added a tweak to get rid of leading zeros: RANDOM=$(date +%s%N | cut -b10-19 | sed -e 's/^0*//;s/^$/0/')

Comment: @JCCyC Interesting idea! Why remove blanks and swap with `0` though? i.e. that should not happen to start with?

Comment: it happened to me, the first of the last 9 digits coming from `date +%s%N` was sometimes zero and the code I fed the numbers to thought it was octal. :-O The second s command is for the rare case in which the 9 last digits are all zero, to guarantee the output will not be empty but a single "0".

Comment: In fact, it happens during one second every 10 seconds -- whenever the integer number of Epoch seconds ends with 0. Try this one for fun:
while [ 1 ]; do echo -en `date +"%s %N"`" "`date +%s%N | cut -b10-19`"\r"; done

Comment: Urgh, backquote messed things up. Lemme try again.
`while [ 1 ]; do echo -en $(date +"%s %N")" "$(date +%s%N | cut -b10-19)"\r"; done`

Comment: @JCCyC A better option to strip the leading zero, instead of using `sed` (a separate program), is Bash's parameter expansion: `${RANDOM#0}`.

Comment: @legends2k That would not work, as the issue is in the `RANDOM=...` assignment. I've fixed the answer to include a `0`-fix using `sed`.

Comment: @Roel You're right, I missed the point that we've to assign to `RANDOM` without the leading zero to seed the random number generator.  Using another variable is an option though: [live example](https://onlinegdb.com/B1JJRkauv); an extra line but not an extra process.  Thanks for the answer and the links :)

Answer (score 7):

If you are using a linux system you can get a random number out of [/dev/random or](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random) /dev/urandom. Be carefull /dev/random will block if there are not enough random numbers available. If you need speed over randomness use /dev/urandom.

These "files" will be filled with random numbers generated by the operating system. It depends on the implementation of /dev/random on your system if you get true or pseudo random numbers. True random numbers are generated with help form noise gathered from device drivers like mouse, hard drive, network.

You can get random numbers from the file with [dd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_%28Unix%29)

Answer (score 6):

What about:

```
perl -e 'print int rand 10, "\n"; '
```

Comment: For a cryptographically secure random number, you need to read from /dev/urandom or use the Crypt::Random libraries.

Answer (score 6):

Reading from /dev/random or /dev/urandom character special files is the way to go.

> These devices return truly random numbers when read and are designed
>   to help application software choose secure keys for encryption. Such
>   random numbers are extracted from an entropy pool that is contributed
>   by various random events. {LDD3, Jonathan Corbet, Alessandro
>   Rubini, and Greg Kroah-Hartman]

These two files are interface to kernel randomization, in particular

```
void get_random_bytes_arch(void* buf, int nbytes)
```

which draws truly random bytes from hardware if such function is by hardware implemented (usually is), or it draws from entropy pool (comprised of timings between events like mouse and keyboard interrupts and other interrupts that are registered with SA_SAMPLE_RANDOM).

```
dd if=/dev/urandom count=4 bs=1 | od -t d
```

This works, but writes unneeded output from `dd` to stdout.  The command below gives just the integer I need. I can even get specified number of random bits as I need by adjustment of the bitmask given to arithmetic expansion:

```
me@mymachine:~/$ x=$(head -c 1 /dev/urandom > tmp && hexdump 
                         -d tmp | head -n 1 | cut -c13-15) && echo $(( 10#$x & 127 ))
```

Answer (score 6):

Maybe I am a bit too late, but what about using `jot` to generate a random number within a range in Bash?

```
jot -r -p 3 1 0 1
```

This generates a random (`-r`) number with 3 decimal places precision (`-p`). In this particular case, you'll get one number between 0 and 1 (`1 0 1`). You can also print sequential data. The source of the random number, according to the manual, is:

> Random numbers are obtained through arc4random(3) when no seed is specified, and through
>        random(3) when a seed is given.

Comment: Must be installed: sudo apt install athena-jot

Comment: Works out of the box on macOS 10.14.

Answer (score 6):

Pure Bash random number without [moduloing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)

```
lowerRange=10   # inclusive
upperRange=20   # exclusive

randomNumber=$(( RANDOM * ( upperRange - lowerRange) / 32767 + lowerRange ))
```

Comment: Probably the best solution. Simple & flexible.

Comment: using lowerRange=1 and upperRange=1000000 this solution works while others with % won't,

Answer (score 5):

I have taken a few of these ideas and made a function that should perform quickly if lots of random numbers are required.

calling `od` is expensive if you need lots of random numbers. Instead I call it once and store 1024 random numbers from /dev/urandom. When `rand` is called, the last random number is returned and scaled. It is then removed from cache. When cache is empty, another 1024 random numbers is read.

Example:

```
rand 10; echo $RET
```

Returns a random number in RET between 0 and 9 inclusive.

```
declare -ia RANDCACHE
declare -i RET RAWRAND=$(( (1<<32)-1 ))

function rand(){  # pick a random number from 0 to N-1. Max N is 2^32
  local -i N=$1
  [[ ${#RANDCACHE[*]} -eq 0 ]] && { RANDCACHE=( $(od -An -tu4 -N1024 /dev/urandom) ); }  # refill cache
  RET=$(( (RANDCACHE[-1]*N+1)/RAWRAND ))  # pull last random number and scale
  unset RANDCACHE[${#RANDCACHE[*]}-1]     # pop read random number
};

# test by generating a lot of random numbers, then effectively place them in bins and count how many are in each bin.

declare -i c; declare -ia BIN

for (( c=0; c<100000; c++ )); do
  rand 10
  BIN[RET]+=1  # add to bin to check distribution
done

for (( c=0; c<10; c++ )); do
  printf "%d %d\n" $c ${BIN[c]} 
done
```

UPDATE: That does not work so well for all N. It also wastes random bits if used with small N. Noting that (in this case) a 32 bit random number has enough entropy for 9 random numbers between 0 and 9 (10**9=1,000,000,000 <= 2**32) we can extract multiple random numbers from each 32 random source value.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -ia RCACHE

declare -i RET             # return value
declare -i ENT=2           # keep track of unused entropy as 2^(entropy)
declare -i RND=RANDOM%ENT  # a store for unused entropy - start with 1 bit

declare -i BYTES=4         # size of unsigned random bytes returned by od
declare -i BITS=8*BYTES    # size of random data returned by od in bits
declare -i CACHE=16        # number of random numbers to cache
declare -i MAX=2**BITS     # quantum of entropy per cached random number
declare -i c

function rand(){  # pick a random number from 0 to 2^BITS-1
  [[ ${#RCACHE[*]} -eq 0 ]] && { RCACHE=( $(od -An -tu$BYTES -N$CACHE /dev/urandom) ); }  # refill cache - could use /dev/random if CACHE is small
  RET=${RCACHE[-1]}              # pull last random number and scale
  unset RCACHE[${#RCACHE[*]}-1]  # pop read random number
};

function randBetween(){
  local -i N=$1
  [[ ENT -lt N ]] && {  # not enough entropy to supply ln(N)/ln(2) bits
    rand; RND=RET       # get more random bits
    ENT=MAX             # reset entropy
  }
  RET=RND%N  # random number to return
  RND=RND/N  # remaining randomness
  ENT=ENT/N  # remaining entropy
};

declare -ia BIN

for (( c=0; c<100000; c++ )); do
  randBetween 10
  BIN[RET]+=1
done

for c in ${BIN[*]}; do
  echo $c
done
```

Comment: I tried this - it took 10 seconds of 100% cpu and then printed 10 numbers that didn't look random at ALL.

Comment: I remember now. This code generates 100,000 random numbers. It puts each in a 'bin' to look at how random it is. There are 10 bins. These numbers should be similar if each random number between 0 and 9 is equally likely. If you want to print each number, echo $RET after randBetween 10.

Comment: `od -An -tu4 -N40 /dev/urandom` will generate 10 random unsigned 32 bit integers separated with whitespace. you can store it in an array and use it afterwards. your code seems to be an overkill.

Comment: @Ali, OP did not specify that they wanted 32 bit nor any other sized random number. I and some others interpreted this question as providing a random number within a range. My rand function achieves this goal and also reduces loss of entropy that, if exhausted, causes programs to block. od on /dev/urandom returns only 2^N bit random numbers and OP would then need to store multiple values into an array, sequentially extracting them from this array, and replenishing this array. Perhaps you can code this as an answer and handle other random number ranges?

Comment: @philcolbourn, you are correct about the OP not specifying what kind of random number he wants and it missed my attention. But he only asked: "How to generate **a** random number in bash?". My point is that he only asked for one random number. Albeit this critic applies to my previous comment (generating **10** random numbers) as well.

Answer (score 4):

Generate random number in the range of 0 to n (signed 16-bit integer). Result set in $RAND variable. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

random()
{
    local range=${1:-1}

    RAND=`od -t uI -N 4 /dev/urandom | awk '{print $2}'`
    let "RAND=$RAND%($range+1)"
}

n=10
while [ $(( n -=1 )) -ge "0" ]; do
    random 500
    echo "$RAND"
done
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a seed, see [documentation](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/randomvar.html):

```
RANDOM=$(date +%s%N | cut -b10-19)
echo $(( $RANDOM % 100 + 1 ))
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on the great answers of @Nelson, @Barun and @Robert, here is a Bash script that generates random numbers.

- Can generate how many digits you want.
- each digit is separately generated by `/dev/urandom` which is **much better** than Bash's built-in `$RANDOM`

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

digits=10

rand=$(od -A n -t d -N 2 /dev/urandom |tr -d ' ')
num=$((rand % 10))
while [ ${#num} -lt $digits ]; do
  rand=$(od -A n -t d -N 1 /dev/urandom |tr -d ' ')
  num="${num}$((rand % 10))"
done
echo $num
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a function I wrote which will output a random number in a desired range>

Description:

> `random <min> <max>`
>
> Generate a random number from `min` to `max`, inclusive. Both `min` and `max` can be
> positive OR negative numbers, and the generated random number can be negative too, so
> long as the range `(max - min + 1)` is less than or equal to `32767`. Max must be >= min.

The core of it is this:

```bash
random() {
    min="$1"
    max="$2"
    
    range=$((max - min + 1))
    rand=$((min + (RANDOM % range)))
    echo "$rand"
}
```

Usage:

```bash
# general form: obtain a random number between min and max, inclusive
random <min> <max>

# Example: obtain a random number from -10 to 10, inclusive
random -10 10
```

This works from the bash built-in variable `RANDOM`, which probably just uses C `rand()` under the hood, since they both have a max value of 32767--see:

1. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/rand
2. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/RAND_MAX

For the bash documentation, see `man bash`:

> **`RANDOM`**
>
> Each time this parameter is referenced, a random integer between `0` and `32767` is generated. The sequence of random numbers may be initialized by assigning a value to `RANDOM`.   If `RANDOM` is `unset`, it loses its special properties, even if it is subsequently reset.

### Robust, runnable, `source`able version of the script

Here is a much more robust version of my `random` function above. It includes full error checking, bounds checking, a help menu via `random --help` or `random -h`, and a special `run_check` feature which allows you to source OR run this script so that you can `source` it to import the `random` function into any other script--just like you can do in Python!

[**random.sh**](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/blob/master/useful_scripts/random.sh) <-- click this link to always get the latest version from my [eRCaGuy_dotfiles](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles) repo.

```bash
RETURN_CODE_SUCCESS=0
RETURN_CODE_ERROR=1

HELP_STR="\
Generate a random integer number according to the usage styles below.

USAGE STYLES:
    'random'
        Generate a random number from 0 to 32767, inclusive (same as bash variable 'RANDOM').
    'random <max>'
        Generate a random number from 0 to 'max', inclusive.
    'random <min> <max>'
        Generate a random number from 'min' to 'max', inclusive. Both 'min' and 'max' can be
        positive OR negative numbers, and the generated random number can be negative too, so
        long as the range (max - min + 1) is less than or equal to 32767. Max must be >= min.

This file is part of eRCaGuy_dotfiles: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles
"

print_help() {
    echo "$HELP_STR" | less -RFX
}

# Get a random number according to the usage styles above.
# See also `utils_rand()` in utilities.c:
# https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/c/utilities.c#L176
random() {
    # PARSE ARGUMENTS

    # help menu
    if [ "$1" = "-h" ] || [ "$1" = "--help" ]; then
        print_help
        exit $RETURN_CODE_SUCCESS
    fi

    # 'random'
    if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
        min=0
        max="none"
    # 'random max'
    elif [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
        min=0
        max="$1"
    # 'random min max'
    elif [ $# -eq 2 ]; then
        min="$1"
        max="$2"
    else
        echo "ERROR: too many arguments."
        exit "$RETURN_CODE_ERROR"
    fi

    # CHECK FOR ERRORS

    if [ "$max" = "none" ]; then
        rand="$RANDOM"
        echo "$rand"
        exit "$RETURN_CODE_SUCCESS"
    fi

    if [ "$max" -lt "$min" ]; then
        echo "ERROR: max ($max) < min ($min). Max must be >= min."
        exit "$RETURN_CODE_ERROR"
    fi

    # CALCULATE THE RANDOM NUMBER

    # See `man bash` and search for `RANDOM`. This is a limitation of that value.
    RAND_MAX=32767

    range=$((max - min + 1))
    if [ "$range" -gt "$RAND_MAX" ]; then
        echo "ERROR: the range (max - min + 1) is too large. Max allowed = $RAND_MAX, but actual" \
             "range = ($max - $min + 1) = $range."
        exit "$RETURN_CODE_ERROR"
    fi

    # NB: `RANDOM` is a bash built-in variable. See `man bash`, and also here:
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/1195035/4561887
    rand=$((min + (RANDOM % range)))
    echo "$rand"
}

# Set the global variable `run` to "true" if the script is being **executed** (not sourced) and
# `main` should run, and set `run` to "false" otherwise. One might source this script but intend
# NOT to run it if they wanted to import functions from the script.
# See:
# 1. *****https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/bash/argument_parsing__3_advanced__gen_prog_template.sh
# 1. my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70662049/4561887
# 1. https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/bash/check_if_sourced_or_executed.sh
run_check() {
    # This is akin to `if __name__ == "__main__":` in Python.
    if [ "${FUNCNAME[-1]}" == "main" ]; then
        # This script is being EXECUTED, not sourced
        run="true"
    fi
}

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Main program entry point
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Only run main function if this file is being executed, NOT sourced.
run="false"
run_check
if [ "$run" == "true" ]; then
    random "$@"
fi
```

### Todo

1. [ ] Make a new answer with a modern C++-based `uniform_int_distribution`, auto-built for your Linux system, and called in Bash. [See here](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/issues/14).

Comment: TODO: make a new answer with a modern C++-based `uniform_int_distribution`, auto-built for your Linux system, and called in Bash. [See here](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/issues/14).

Answer (score 2):

Random branching of a program or yes/no; 1/0; true/false output:

```
if [ $RANDOM -gt 16383  ]; then              # 16383 = 32767/2 
    echo var=true/1/yes/go_hither
else 
    echo var=false/0/no/go_thither
fi
```

of if you lazy to remember 16383:

```
if (( RANDOM % 2 )); then 
    echo "yes"
else 
    echo "no"
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

Wanted to use /dev/urandom without **dd** and **od**

```
function roll() { local modulus=${1:-6}; echo $(( 1 + 0x$(env LC_CTYPE=C tr -dc '0-9a-fA-F' < /dev/urandom | head -c5 ) % $modulus )); }
```

Testing

```
$ roll
5
$ roll 12
12
```

Just how random is it?

```
$ (echo "count roll percentage"; i=0; while [ $i -lt 10000 ]; do roll; i=$((i+1)); done | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $0,($1/10000*100)"%"}') | column -t
count  roll  percentage
1625   1     16.25%
1665   2     16.65%
1646   3     16.46%
1720   4     17.2%
1694   5     16.94%
1650   6     16.5%
```

Answer (score 2):

## Generate random 3-digit number

This is great for creating sample data. Example: put all testing data in a directory called "test-create-volume-123", then after your test is done, zap the entire directory. By generating exactly three digits, you don't have [weird sorting issues](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/127644/48539).

```
printf '%02d\n' $((1 + RANDOM % 100))
```

This scales down, e.g. to one digit:

```
printf '%01d\n' $((1 + RANDOM % 10))
```

It scales up, but *only to four digits*. See above as to why :)

Answer (score 1):

A bash function that uses perl to generate a random number of n digits. Specify either the number of digits or a template of n 0s.

```
rand() {
  perl -E '$ARGV[0]||=""; $ARGV[0]=int($ARGV[0])||length($ARGV[0]); say join "", int(rand(9)+1)*($ARGV[0]?1:0), map { int(rand(10)) } (0..($ARGV[0]||0)-2)' $1
}
```

Usage:

```
$ rand 3
381
$ rand 000
728
```

Demonstration of calling rand n, for n between 0 and 15:

```
$ for n in {0..15}; do printf "%02d: %s\n" $n $(rand $n); done
00: 0
01: 3
02: 98
03: 139
04: 1712
05: 49296
06: 426697
07: 2431421
08: 82727795
09: 445682186
10: 6368501779
11: 51029574113
12: 602518591108
13: 5839716875073
14: 87572173490132
15: 546889624135868
```

Demonstration of calling rand n, for n a template of 0s between length 0 and 15

```
$ for n in {0..15}; do printf "%15s :%02d: %s\n" $(printf "%0${n}d" 0) $n $(rand $(printf "%0${n}d" 0)); done
              0 :00: 0
              0 :01: 0
             00 :02: 70
            000 :03: 201
           0000 :04: 9751
          00000 :05: 62237
         000000 :06: 262860
        0000000 :07: 1365194
       00000000 :08: 83953419
      000000000 :09: 838521776
     0000000000 :10: 2355011586
    00000000000 :11: 95040136057
   000000000000 :12: 511889225898
  0000000000000 :13: 7441263049018
 00000000000000 :14: 11895209107156
000000000000000 :15: 863219624761093
```

Answer (score 0):

No other dependency is needed:

```bash
$(((RANDOM % $((upperBound - lowerBound))) + lowerBound))
```

The random number range is `[lowerBound,upperBound)`

Comment: Is the upperBound inclusive or exclusive?

Comment: lowerBound inclusive, upperBound exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

random numbers from 001 to 087

```
$ printf "%03d" $(shuf -i 1-87 -n 1 )
```

As an example of actually using it, the Aleph With Beth videos all look something like:

039 - Verbs come & go (qatal singular) - Lesson 21.mp4

and this command:

```
$ mpv -fs $(printf "%03d" $(shuf -i 1-87 -n 1 ))*
```

plays a random video from the first 87, for revision purposes.

Answer (score 0):

For a random number with fixed number of digits (e.g. 8):

```
cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc '0-9' | fold -w 8 | head -n 1
```

And in case you need a random string use:

```
cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 8 | head -n 1
```

Ref: https://gist.github.com/earthgecko/3089509