# How to generate random numbers in the buffer?

Tags: vim, vi

I want to generate 10 random numbers in the buffer.

In Emacs I would do:

`<start macro>(random limit) <eval lisp><newline><end macro>` to define the macro,

and `9 <execute macro>` to generate it 10 times.

Is there a way I can do this in vim?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

is this ok for you?

```
:r! echo $RANDOM
```

then

```
9@:
```

if you have certain programming language env available on your OS, you can eval those statement too.

Comment: Know of an equivalent in gVim?

Comment: @Jeff That works on gVim. I was on windows, so replaced $random with %random%. Rest just worked

Comment: I was trying this on windows but the command in the answer didn't work. So, I opened up vim inside cygwin and then it worked.

Comment: @user674669 of course it won't work on windows, because there is no `$RANDOM` sys env on windows. `:!` will execute external command. Just like there is no `du, ls, readlink, cp ...` on windows.  Well cygwin I don't have much experience..

Comment: In addition, you could use `:r!echo $(($RANDOM \% 5 + 1))` to get a value between 1 and 6. Tweak values accordingly to get other ranges.

Answer (score 11):

Vim doesn't offer native random generator, however if you have vim compiled with Python, the following method will append a random digit at the end of your line:

```
:py import vim, random; vim.current.line += str(random.randint(0, 9))
```

<sup>Note: To check if your vim supports Python, try: `:echo has('python')` (1 for yes).</sup>

You can also use shell which offers `$RANDOM` variable as Kent suggested (works with bash/ksh/zsh) which returns a pseudorandom (0-32767), in example:

```
:put =system('echo $RANDOM')
```

or:

```
:r! od -An -td -N1 /dev/urandom
```

<sup>On Windows, you've to have Cygwin/MSYS/SUA installed, or use `%RANDOM%` variable as [Carpetsmoker](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/812/467) suggested.</sup>

If you don't have access to shell and Python, as for workaround, you use last few digits from the current timestamp, in example:

```
:put =reltimestr(reltime())[-2:]
```

<sup>Note: If you're using it quite often, write a simple function which will `return reltimestr(reltime())[-4:]`.</sup>

> Note: Above methods returns only a pseudorandom integer which should not be used to generate an encryption key.

---

To add more random numbers please press <kbd>@</kbd><kbd>:</kbd> to repeat the command again. Or prefix with number (like <kbd>10</kbd><kbd>@</kbd><kbd>:</kbd>) to add much more of random numbers separated by new lines.

---

Related:

- [How to generate random numbers?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/807/467) at Vim SE
- [Generate random number in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194882/generate-random-number) at stackoverflow SE

Comment: For perl, `:put =system("perl -e `int(rand()*10)+1") can be tried, for example. :)