# Generating random numbers that conform to a range in Bash

Tags: bash, random, arguments

If I run `./random.sh 10 45`, it would only return random numbers between `10` and `45`.

I am able to produce the random number using

```
randomNumber=$((1 + RANDOM % 100))
```

but now how can I allow user to specify upper and lower limit of random number?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [shuf](https://linux.die.net/man/1/shuf)

```
#!/bin/bash

# $1: Lower limit
# $2: Upper limit
# Todo  Check arguments

shuf -i $1-$2 -n 1
```

`./random.sh 45 50`

Comment: This use an external tool instead of using bash built-in mechanisms. Thus random.sh become much more a wrapper than a tool by itself.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following (pure BASH):

```
   low=10
   hgh=45
   rand=$((low + RANDOM%(1+hgh-low)))
```

Answer (score 3):

The trouble with modulo is that `$RANDOM % N`, unless N is a power of 2, does not have an equal probability distribution for all results: [How to generate random number in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194882/how-to-generate-random-number-in-bash#comment36748687_1195035). Per `man bash`, `$RANDOM` produces a number between 0 and 32,767 (2**15-1). This may not matter much in some situations, but by rewriting the expression slightly we do get an equal distribution.

```
for i in {0..10}; do echo -n "$((RANDOM*36/32768 + 10)) "; done; echo
```

A bash script with a user-selectable range:

```
#!/bin/bash
LOW=$1
HIGH=$2
echo $((RANDOM * ($HIGH-$LOW+1) / 32768 + LOW))
```

You will want to do some parameter checking also.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to set your range at a default lower bound, say `10`, with a higher bound, say `45`. So you adjust the lower bound like this : `$RANDOM % 45 + 10`, don't you?

But there is a problem with this solution, it assumes that you'll always be between `0 + 10` and `45` so in fact it works until you reach 35 (`35 + 10 = 45` your higher bound), anymore than `35` will be out of your bounds.

The solution in order to stay in the range is to do `$RANDOM % (higher_b - lower_b)` which will allow you to stay in higher bound then to add lower bound which gives you :

```
$RANDOM % (45 -10) + 10
```

example wrong output:

```
for i in {0..10};do printf $[RANDOM % 45 + 10]" ";done
47 31 53 23 36 10 22 36 11 25 54
```

example right output:

```
for i in {0..10};do printf $[RANDOM % 35 +10]" ";done
39 44 14 12 38 31 25 13 42 33 16
```

You can also write `RANDOM % (higher - lower +1)` if you want your index to include higher bound.