# How to generate random number in GitLab YAML file

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci

I have YAML file in my Gitlab branch. As per the requirement i want to create one random mergeID in YAML file.

Comment: Can you give code that you have tested?

Comment: YAML is not a programming language and therefore can't generate random numbers. The gitlab-ci-runner tag makes no sense because that is configured with TOML, not YAML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're referring to the gitlab-ci.yml file, this is possible. Each GitLab job defined in the YAML file provides a `script` section where you can define bash commands that will get executed by GitLab when the job is run. If you want more complex operations, you can call Python scripts from the script section.

Fortunately, in this case, bash has a built-in `$RANDOM` function, described in [How to generate random number in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194882/how-to-generate-random-number-in-bash).

gitlab-ci.yml:

```yaml
my-job:
  stage: my-stage
  script:
    # Generate random number from 1 to 10:
    - let MR_ID=$((1 + RANDOM % 10))
```

More info on GitLab scripts: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#script

Comment: Thank you very much, It's looks like resolve my requirement!!!

Comment: Here I have one more requirement i.e: Generate seven digit random number. So I modified the code like below                                                                                        
    - let SevenDigitMR_ID=RANDOM -MINIMUM 999999 -MAXIMUM 9999999
    - echo $SevenDigitMR_ID                                                                                                                                       But still it's generate the same five digit random number only. By default  $RANDOM generate the number up to 5 digits only.

Comment: Search stackoverflow for an answer. If you can't find one, post another question ;)

Answer (score 7):

Another simple solution without using script is to use the gitlab env variable `CI_JOB_ID`.
It's not a random number, but it's unique.

```
variables:
  MERGE_ID: $CI_JOB_ID
```