# How to generate random numbers then pass it to a command line argument?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line-arguments

For example, if I have the following command:

```sh
python generate.py --outdir=out --trunc=1 --seeds=128,8755,90,543468
```

I want to use bash to generate random numbers and place them in the `seeds` argument, and have the seeds be between specific interval (e.g., 1-8000). Like this:

```sh
rand_seed_gen= im_a_func_that_generates_4_random_seeds # pseudo code
python generate.py --outdir=out --trunc=1 --seeds=rand_seed_gen
```

EDIT:
Also, is there a way to multiply the number of random integers without explicitly passing each one individually? For example (again, pseudo code): `${RANDOM} * 10` to return a comma separated list of 10 random integers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate random number in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194882/how-to-generate-random-number-in-bash)

Comment: @dedede : Please don't ask two questions in a single post. Create two different posts for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this

```
python generate.py --outdir=out --trunc=1 --seeds=${RANDOM},${RANDOM},${RANDOM}
```

From the [bash manpage](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Variables)

> RANDOM
>
> Each time this parameter is referenced, it expands to a random integer
> between 0 and 32767. Assigning a value to this variable seeds the
> random number generator. If RANDOM is unset, it loses its special
> properties, even if it is subsequently reset.

But if you need to set a range, what you can do is

```sh
# Generate random numbers, replacing nullbytes with commas
randvars=$(shuf -z -i 1-8000 -n 4 | tr '\0' ',')
# Delete the last comma
randvars=${randvars::-1}

python generate.py --outdir=out --trunc=1 --seeds=${randvars}
```

Where `-i 1-8000` is the range and `-n 4` is the amount you want to return.

Comment: Also, is there a way to multiply the number of random integers without explicitly passing each one individually? For example (again, pseudo code): `${RANDOM} * 10` to return a comma separated list of 10 random integers.

Comment: @dedede Edited the post to include a way to set range

Comment: it didn't work when I did it line by line but it worked when I inserted the whole thing into the argument like this `python generate.py --outdir=out --trunc=1 --seeds=\`randvars=$(shuf -z -i 1-8000 -n 4 | tr '\0' ','); randvars=${randvars::-1}; echo ${randvars}\`

Comment: @dedede You can unquote the `--seeds="${randvars}"` part, so do `--seeds=${randvars}`