# If RANDOM only goes up to 32767, how can I generate a 9-digit random number?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

How to generate 9 digit random number in shell?

I am trying something like this but it only gave numbers below 32768.

```
#!/bin/bash
mo=$((RANDOM%999999999))
echo "********Random"$mo
```

Please help

output should be `********Random453351111`

Comment: You'll need to generate multiple smaller numbers and append them to each other. `RANDOM` only goes up to 32,767.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1195035/11261546) answer your questoin?

Comment: @Ivan, insofar as that doesn't describe how to generate numbers with a wider range than RANDOM itself has, I doubt that it does.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate random number in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194882/how-to-generate-random-number-in-bash)

Comment: No, its not the case @phuclv

Comment: It's not pure shell, but `perl -e'print int rand(1000000)'` will do it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a work around, we could just simply ask for 1 random integer, for `n` times:

```
rand=''
for i in {1..9}; do
    rand="${rand}$(( $RANDOM % 10 ))"
done

echo $rand
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vygxL8VWXZ0rLb9IIVMhM0@h2lBPz7LWWiEln0sBCMDySirVILpWRUNDQSXI0c/F31dBVcHQQEFTU4krJT8vlYsrNTkjX0EFpOr/fwA)

---

**Note** <sup>[[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66802734/if-random-only-goes-up-to-32767-how-can-i-generate-a-9-digit-random-number/66802943#comment118087321_66802943)</sup>: Since `RANDOM`'s upper limit has a final digit of `7`, there's a slightly lesser change for the 'generated' number to contain `8` or `9`'s.

Comment: BTW, this is ever-so-slightly biased. Because `RANDOM` goes up to a number with a final digit of 7, that means 8 and 9 are slightly less likely than the digits below them.

Answer (score 3):

In Linux with `/dev/urandom`:

```
$ rnd=$(tr -cd "[:digit:]" < /dev/urandom | head -c 9) && echo $rnd
463559879
```

Comment: This works, but it's really unfortunate to be eating so much more data from `/dev/urandom` than you really need (since anything that isn't a digit just gets thrown out). A better way to use `/dev/urandom` would be to read only a single 64-bit integer _as 64 bits of data_, so the total amount of entropy consumed is constrained to 8 bytes -- though that's easier to write in Python or C than bash.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should make it

```
shuf -i 99999999-999999999 -n 1
```

Comment: Even better with allowing leading zeros: `printf '%010d\n' $(shuf -i 0-999999999 -n 1)`

Comment: `printf '%09d\n' $(shuf -i 0-999999999 -n 1)` for this particular case :)

Answer (score 1):

Because of RANDOM's limited range, it can only be used to retrieve four base-10 digits at a time. Thus, to retrieve 9 digits, you need to call it three times.

If we don't care much about performance (are willing to pay process substitution costs), this may look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
get4() {
  local newVal=32768
  while (( newVal > 29999 )); do # avoid bias because of remainder
    newVal=$RANDOM
  done
  printf '%04d' "$((newVal % 10000))"
}

result="$(get4)$(get4)$(get4)"
result=$(( result % 1000000000 ))
printf '%09d\n' "$result"
```

If we *do* care about performance, it may instead look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
get4() {
  local newVal=32768 outVar=$1
  while (( newVal > 29999 )); do # avoid bias because of remainder
    newVal=$RANDOM
  done
  printf -v "$outVar" '%04d' "$((newVal % 10000))"
}

get4 out1; get4 out2; get4 out3
result="${out1}${out2}${out3}"
result=$(( result % 1000000000 ))
printf '%09d\n' "$result"
```

Comment: Let me try this too.

Comment: _nod_ -- the 1-digit-at-a-time way works, but it consumes more entropy than it needs; 4-at-a-time is faster (when you use the version that isn't slowed down by use of `$(...)`); and also this provides a more random number on account of rerolling things that don't divide evenly into 10,000.

Answer (score 0):

Use perl, as follows :

```
perl -e print\ rand | cut -c 3-11
```

Or

```
perl -MPOSIX -e 'print floor rand 10**9'
```