# How to generate random even number as parameter of function in bash one line command?

Tags: bash, random, terminal

I need to set random even number as function parameter in terminal:
`soapy_power -b random_even_number`

First step, I generate random number with `shuf -i1-10 -n1`
Next,I try to judge whether random number is even,if not `+1` to this number.

What I tried and failed:
`$(((shuf -i1-10 -n1) %2 -eq 0 OR (shuf -i1-10 -n1)+1))`

How to generate random even number as parameter of function in bash one line command?

Comment: `$(( $(shuf -i1-5 -n1) * 2))`; though a solution referencing `$RANDOM` (eg, pjh's answer) eliminates the overhead of invoking a sub-process call

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate random number in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194882/how-to-generate-random-number-in-bash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
soapy_power -b "$(( RANDOM%5*2+2 ))"
```