# How to shuffle a list of sequence numbers in bash

Tags: bash, random

I want to generate the random numbers and then use it as the "`index`" to get the data from other array list.

Given a number `5`, and then generate `5 numbers` in the sequence of `[1..5]`, and then `shuffle` them into the random order.

**Here are two examples output after shuffling the numbers:**

```
1, 3, 5, 2, 4
2, 5, 1, 4, 3
```

Gien a number `100`, then generate `100 numbers` in `[1...100]`, then shuffle them using the same method.

**Now define a shuffle function in bash:**

```
shuffle_numbers() {
    local range="$1"
    
    # Use method from "Mark Setchell"
    # numbers=( $seq 100 | shuf )
    
    # The value of numbers should be:
    # 1, 3, 5, 2, 4
    # or
    # 2, 5, 1, 4, 3
    # or
    # ..other random orders if the $range is 5.
    # or
    # ... 100 random orders if the $range is 100...
    
    sprintf "%s" "$numbers"
}
```

How to implement the `shuffle_numbers` in bash?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate random number in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194882/how-to-generate-random-number-in-bash)

Comment: That link can't solve this question as the output does not match. I want to get a list of all "random" but not "duplicated" numbers as the return result instead of just return only 1 random number in that range.

Comment: I do not understand. `generate the random numbers and then use it as the "index"` Do you want to generate one random number and index another array with it? Or you want to generate a list of random numbers and generate indexes or another array? __or__ do you want to shuffle an array?  Is this XY question? `That link can't solve` Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/38865224/9072753 "solve" it with `seq` command?

Comment: Generate the numbers and shuffle them into an array. Pop one element on each call. `numbers=( $seq 100 | shuf) )`

Comment: I think "shuffle" is the correct word for this question. I tried "numbers=( $seq 100 | shuf)" but got "bash: syntax error near unexpected token `|'".

Comment: @EdMorton Yes, I agree. I think that is what the OP wants.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `a=( $(seq 10 | shuf ))`

Comment: FYI there's no `sprintf` in bash. The equivalent to `var=$( sprintf '%s' "$numbers" )`, if it existed, is `printf -v var '%s' "$numbers"`

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I was suggesting in the comments...

Create a sequence of 10 numbers, 1..10 and shuffle them into an array `a`:

```
a=( $(seq 10 | shuf ))
```

Examine array contents:

```
echo "${a[*]}"
1 2 9 5 8 4 7 10 6 3
```

Pop last element, examine it and remove from array:

```
r="${a[-1]}"
echo "$r"
3    
unset 'a[-1]'        # remove last element
echo "${a[*]}"       # check what's left
1 2 9 5 8 4 7 10 6
```

---

I think `unset` requires `bash` v4.3 or so, as that aspect won't work on the ancient `bash` v3.2 that Apple ships with macOS.