How to replace random lines with empty string 30% of the time in bash?
Assuming that I created a file with 10 lines:
yes "foo bar" | head -n 10 > foobar.txt

[out]:
foo bar
foo bar
foo bar
foo bar
foo bar
foo bar
foo bar
foo bar
foo bar
foo bar

And I want to randomly replace 30% of the lines with empty line to look like this:
foo bar

foo bar

foo bar

foo bar
foo bar

foo bar

I could technically write a python script to generate random num and do ratio-foobar.sh
#!/bin/bash

ratio=$1
numlines=$2

coinflip() {
  randnum=$(bc -l <<< $(python -S -c "import random; print(int(random.random() * 100))"))
  if [ $randnum -gt $ratio ]
  then 
     return 1
  else
     return 0
  fi
}

for i in $(seq 1 $numlines);
do
  if coinflip
  then
    echo "foo bar"
  else
    echo ""
  fi
done

Usage:
bash ratio-foobar.sh 33 10 > foobar.txt

[out]:
foo bar
foo bar
foo bar

foo bar


foo bar
foo bar



But is there a simpler way to just generate (maybe with yes) a certain percent of the time?

Tried to use @renaud-pacalet solution but I realized the whole reading float into shell thing was a mess and somehow bc got involved again. But somehow this didn't work:
ratio=$1
lines=$2

ratio=$(echo "scale=3; $ratio/100" | bc)

yes "foo bar" | head -n $2 | awk 'BEGIN {srand()} {print rand() < $ratio ? "" : $0}' > output

cat output

Use: bash flip.sh 33 10 for 33% and 10 lines of foo bar.
But when the ratio is hard-coded, it worked:
ratio=$1
lines=$2

ratio=$(echo "scale=3; $ratio/100" | bc)

yes "foo bar" | head -n $2 | awk 'BEGIN {srand()} {print rand() < 0.3? "" : $0}' > output

cat output

Any solution to do this reading of the percentage and make the yes | head | awk works properly?

You can get a random number with $RANDOM instead of calling bc. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194882/how-to-generate-random-number-in-bash

If python is an option why don't you use only that and code a python script  (with arguments if you want it to be flexible) that does the whole thing?

As you can apparently use python you could use only that:
from random import randrange as rnd
def foo(n, r, s):
    for i in range(n):
        print("" if rnd(100) < r else s)
foo(10, 33, "foo bar")

Where n is the number of lines to print, r is the percentage of empty lines and s is the string to print. See the argparse module if you want to pass arguments to a python script.
You could do the same with any POSIX awk (tested with GNU awk):
awk -v n=10 -v r=33 -v s="foo bar" '
END {srand(); for(i=1; i<=n; i++) print rand() < r/100 ? "" : s}' /dev/null

Or, with plain bash:
n=10; r=33; s="foo bar"
for (( i=1; i<=n; i++ )) ; do
  (( SRANDOM % 100 < r )) && echo "" || echo "$s"
done

The SRANDOM special variable expands as a 32 bits random number. So, it could be that you don't get exactly 33% of empty lines (2 to the power of 32 is not a multiple of 100) but the difference should be very small.

Thank you!! That makes the whole bc + python -c mess go away =)

@alvas You didn't want to accept it?

@Renaud-Pacalet somehow I got into another rabbit hole of trying to use bc to read the floats... Any solution there?

See my updated answer.
